# Ubuntu 22.04: xfce4-panel shows high cpu, possible fix?

Tags: 22.04, xfce, cpu

When using xfce as GUI for ubuntu 22.04 I sometimes get high CPU usage according to `htop`, sometimes over 60%.
I use Ubuntu 22.04LTS and xfce4-panel 4.16.3 (Xfce 4.16)
I have searched the internet, but the only solution I found was `xfce4-panel --restart` which does help, but only temporarily. Is there a structual solution for this ?
I thought about a cron job every two hours, but cron cannot access an X display, and is just another bandage rather than a real solution.
Do some apps (Thunar, Brave, Firefox, Stellarium) surge the CPU usage ?
Update: I found that switching themes is one of the causes.
I fixed it by appending `xfce4-panel --restart` or `xfce4-panel -r` after the command to switch themes in the launch panel 'dark mode'.

So my switch to light mode is now:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Light mode
Exec=sh -c "/usr/bin/xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Net/ThemeName -s Kimi-v40 && xfce4-panel -r"
Icon=goa-panel
Categories=System
X-XFCE-Source=file:///home/user/.local/share/Applications/Light.desktop
Comment=
Path=
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
```

Might be a solution, I'll try.

Does anybody recognize this issue ?